# HERE-Android Prem SDK NavigationManager.RerouteListener

Tags: android, here-api

Why is the NavigationManager.RerouteListener not always called when I deviate from the route? 
If this method is still called out, is it necessary to install a new Route in  NavigationManager?

```
NavigationManager.getInstance().setRoute(route)
```

or does it happen automatically?

I can not find a parameter indicating whether I am on the route. Is there such a parameter and how to call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HereMaps SDK has some calculations to call the reroute listener. Like, is the user approaching the destination in any way or going away from the destination.

I observed the listener is called every time I try to go away from the destination.
Distance to reroute depends on many parameters like route, transport mode, traffice etc.

NavigationManager doesn't need to be set with the new route.
But, if you are showing the route object on Map, then clear the old route and redraw the new route.

Comment: I am also facing the issue.Please let me know how did you over come this issue